# Box containing coins - Finding sets from the box of coins

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> A set of 4 coins is selected from a box containing 8 dimes and 6 quarters
>
> > Find the number of sets of four coins.
> >
> > Find the number of sets in which two are dimes and two are quarters.
> >
> > Find the number of sets composed of all dimes or all quarters.
> >
> > Find the number of sets with three or more quarters.

So far, I'm stuck on how to proceed.

For the first one, I assumed there will be $16$ different sets since the set can contain $4$ coins of two different types.  So I did $4^2=16$

So I basically set it up like this:

$c_n$ = a coin

$$S=\{c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4\}$$

$$D=\{8d, 6q\}$$ where $d$ is dimes and $q$ is quarters.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For First: $$\binom80\binom64+\binom81\binom63+\binom82\binom62+\binom83\binom61+\binom84\binom60$$

For second one, try understanding: $$\binom 82\binom62$$

For third: $$\binom80\binom64+\binom84\binom60$$

For fourth: $$\binom 63\binom81+\binom 64\binom80$$

Comment: The problem thinks the dimes and quarters are distinguishable.  For the first line, then it should be $14 \choose 4$  Many of the others exceed $4^2=16$

Comment: @RossMillikan edited, the first one was wrong